# have instructions on installing Tails via Mojave -- what about Catalina?

Tags: tails, mac

ought I follow the instructions given or would I need to anything differently? currently using macOS 10.15.1, i.e. the latest version of Catalina.

Comment: What would you be installing it in? If VMWare or similar, it should be exacctly the same.

Comment: not using VMWare but booting up with via USB stick. anyway, I went through the steps and it worked.